# What is the cause for these patterns on my kiwi fruit?

Tags: fruit

[image]

Have a look at the top right side of the fruit. There are these grid like vellular patterns over it. The fruit seemed tender at time of taking the photo.

Unsure if the pattern developed over ripening or not. Never paid attention except when I took it out of the bag.

Comment: It looks like a giraffe pattern: https://www.google.com/search?q=voronoi+in+nature&sxsrf=AJOqlzUHKjvL203Q28o9-8-PQ5bHU_sXVA:1679211970845&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW-5iIwOf9AhXqVqQEHZcnAf4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1707&bih=863&dpr=1.5

Answer (score 2):

These are blemishes from rubbing of the fruit while on the vine (against other fruit or a branch) or possibly from damage from water sitting on the skin or from a mite or similar parasite.

There should be no or very minor damage below the skin on the part of the fruit that you eat.

Comment: That pattern is called a voronoi it corresponds to cellular shrinkage boundaries, like mud-cracks, giraffe patterns, puff balls, jackfruit skin, cell mushoom pores, fly wing veins, leaf cells, bubble cross sections, skin cells, and it can be found on interactive graphics like https://www.google.com/search?q=shadertoy+voronoi&sxsrf=AJOqlzVOpCKLmiwgEsDk2lcZzMhurWRgAw:1679212442864&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq5aLpwef9AhW6T6QEHVx5C7oQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1707&bih=863&dpr=1.5

Comment: @bandybabboon you should write your own answer, perhaps citing this one, but giving some more background on Voronoi patterns in nature - how and why they form.